# Unable to read from plist file which contains array of arrays and having DIctionaries

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have created a plist file which contain a single array which contains four another array. and each array contains four dictionaries. I have tried alot to read data from the plist file. but unable to get the data.the code of my plist file is here

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>Root</key>
<array>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>name</key>
            <string>Czech Republic</string>
            <key>imagename</key>
            <string>czechrepublic.png</string>
            <key>url</key>
            <string>www.google.com</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>name</key>
            <string>Greece</string>
            <key>imagename</key>
            <string>greece.png</string>
            <key>url</key>
            <string>www.google.com</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>name</key>
            <string>Poland</string>
            <key>imagename</key>
            <string>poland.png</string>
            <key>url</key>
            <string>www.google.com</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>name</key>
            <string>Russia</string>
            <key>imagename</key>
            <string>russia.png</string>
            <key>url</key>
            <string>www.google.com</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>name</key>
            <string>Denmark</string>
            <key>imagename</key>
            <string>denmark.png</string>
            <key>url</key>
            <string>www.google.com</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>name</key>
            <string>Germany</string>
            <key>imagename</key>
            <string>germany.png</string>
            <key>url</key>
            <string>www.google.com</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>name</key>
            <string>Netherlands</string>
            <key>imagename</key>
            <string>netherlands.png</string>
            <key>url</key>
            <string>www.google.com</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>name</key>
            <string>Portugal</string>
            <key>imagename</key>
            <string>portugal.png</string>
            <key>url</key>
            <string>www.google.com</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>name</key>
            <string>Croatia</string>
            <key>imagename</key>
            <string>croatia.png</string>
            <key>url</key>
            <string>www.google.com</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>name</key>
            <string>Italy</string>
            <key>imagename</key>
            <string>italy.png</string>
            <key>url</key>
            <string>www.google.com</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>name</key>
            <string>Republic of Ireland</string>
            <key>imagename</key>
            <string>ireland.png</string>
            <key>url</key>
            <string>www.google.com</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>name</key>
            <string>Spain</string>
            <key>imagename</key>
            <string>spain.png</string>
            <key>url</key>
            <string>www.google.com</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>name</key>
            <string>England</string>
            <key>imagename</key>
            <string>england.png</string>
            <key>url</key>
            <string>www.google.com</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>name</key>
            <string>France</string>
            <key>imagename</key>
            <string>france.png</string>
            <key>url</key>
            <string>www.google.com</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>name</key>
            <string>Sweden</string>
            <key>imagename</key>
            <string>sweden.png</string>
            <key>url</key>
            <string>www.google.com</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>name</key>
            <string>Ukraine</string>
            <key>imagename</key>
            <string>ukraine.png</string>
            <key>url</key>
            <string>www.google.com</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
    </array>
 </dict>
</plist>
```

and the code used for reading from this plist is

```
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
// get documents path
NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
// get the path to our Data/plist file
NSString *plistPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Data.plist"];

// check to see if Data.plist exists in documents
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:plistPath]) 
{
    // if not in documents, get property list from main bundle
    plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Data" ofType:@"plist"];
}

NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath;
NSMutableArray *array = [dict objectForKey:@"Root"];
```

The array is Empty.

Comment: Post the error, we cant read minds.

Comment: the error is that the dictionary is empty

Comment: array is empty or array is nil?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have u tried to code like this:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@”your_Plist_name” ofType:@”plist”];
NSMutableDictionary *saved = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: path]; 
NSArray *arr = [saved objectForKey:@"root"];

for(int i =0;i<4;i++)
{
  NSArray *next = [arr objectAtIndex:i];
    for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
    {
        NSDictionary *dict = [next objectAtIndex:j];

        NSString *value = [dict objectForKey:@"imagename"];
    }
}
```

Try this code and check if it works for you ..

Answer (score 2):

Your plist contain a dictionary which contain a array and that array contains four array and that four array contains dictionaries.

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>Root</key>
```

these line specifies that plist is a dictionary not array.

---

Edited

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath;
NSMutableArray *array = [temp objectForKey:@"Root"];
```

why are you using `temp` here use `dict`

Answer (score 1):

You're missing closing `</dict>` and `</plist>` tags.